# Blender on OS X Sierra 10.12.4 - Menus not working correctly

Tags: python, scripting, installation, osx, versions

When I try to use the file menu is sorta, works but not well.  I cannot click on anything if it appears at all.  Sometimes I get Python: INFO_MT_file instead of the file.

I have deleted ~/Library/Application Support/Blender to make sure there is no cruft. I have tried blender versions 2.69, 2.77 and 2.78c - all have the same poor behavior.[image]

Has anybody see this before?  Googling "Blender INFO_MT_file" gives me nada.

A bad version of a python module on my system or something?

Thanks

Comment: This just happened again.  It's very weird as the only software affected is Blender.  I am now using High Serria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, working with some other Mac software I found the following pattern to clean up stale bits that could be causing bad behavior.

So I did the following `rm -rf  ~/Library/Caches/Blender/*`.  I assume I blew away a few customizations with this as weel.

I will just leave this here and hope it helps someone else.

---

The issue came back.  This time I unplugged all USB peripherals except my mouse and keyboard and the issue disappered.